# Origin of a correction to an integral measure

Tags: measure-theory, electromagnetism

[image]

In the above problem, I can't seem to understand why we include the cosθ term which changes the measure of the integral. The only thing I am able to note is that this corresponds to the dot product of the lines of force with the unit normal of the plane. However, I can't seem to think of a rationale for why this is necessary.

I suspected it was a mathematical one and therefore I have posted this question here.

Comment: What on earth is going on.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the force is an vector quantity. The vector is $\cdots\cos\theta$ downwards and $\cdots\sin\theta$ sideways, but the later component is canceled by the charge at the opposite side.

To elaborate:

$${4\pi\epsilon_0F\over\sigma} = \int {(x,y,r)\over|x,y,r|^3}dS = \int {(R\cos\phi,R\sin\phi,r)\over|R,r|^3}d\phi dR = \int{2\pi R(0,0,r)\over (R^2+r^2)^{3/2}}dR$$

But you have from the definition that $\cos\theta = r/\sqrt{R^2+r^2}$ which makes $(0,0,r)/\sqrt{R^2+r^2} = (0,0,1)\cos\theta$ from which the result follows.

Comment: Oh right ahhaah totally forgot sorry guys. I assumed the integral would take care of itself but forgot I was doing a scalar integral and not a vector one, with the assumption that due to reflectional symmetry in the plane only the perpendicular component of the force makes the contribution.